# How can you assign a variable a value from another class?

Tags: c++, java-native-interface, variable-assignment

I am writing a program that needs a pathname to eventually create a global string. 
I currently have this pathname hard coded, but would like to use a global variable to replace this.
The problem I am having is that my global variable is undefined. I am also using JNI and the error I am getting is:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f65f981ddd0, pid=11660, tid=140075985102592   
#
# JRE version: 7.0_21-b02
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (23.7-b01 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libstdc++.so.6+0x9ddd0]  std::string::size() const+0x0
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/cbil/Desktop/SIGH_Project/July_9/src/hs_err_pid11660.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please include
# instructions on how to reproduce the bug and visit:
#   https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openjdk-7/
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

and here is relevant code that is reformatted for simplicity:

file1.cpp

```
#include <jni.h>
#include "file1.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;
const char* myPath;

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_foo_foo(JNIEnv *env, jobject thisobj, jbyteArray passedPath){

/*Some conversion, don't think it is relevant, but it might be*/

    jboolean isCopy;
    jbyte* path = env->GetByteArrayElements(passedPath,&isCopy);
    int length1 = strlen((const char*)path);
    char* convertedVar = (char*)malloc(length1+1);
    memcpy(convertedVar,path,length1);
    convertedVar[length1] = '\0';
    convertedVar = (char*)path;

/*End Conversion*/

    globalVariable = convertedVar;

    ... //Some code to use the variable and releases

}
```

file2.h (This is where I declare the global variable)

```
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <string.h>

extern const char* globalVariable;
extern int someNum;
extern int someLength;

class file2{
    public:
        static std::vector<std::string> getSomeString(int &someNum, int &someLength);

    private:
        static const std::vector<std::string> anotherVar;

        ...//some other variables and methods

}
```

and finally the code that calls getSomeString

file3.cpp

```
#include "file2.h"
#include <string.h>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int someNum = 0;
int someLength = 0;
const char* globalVariable;
vector<string> file2::getSomeString(int &someNum, iint &someLength){

    vector<string> data;

    ifstream infile(globalVariable); //I think the problem is here

    string line;

    ...// some code that goes through the data file specified by the path name    

    someNum = data.size();
    someLength = data[0].size();


return data;
}

const vector<string> file2::anotherVar = getSomeString(someNum,someLength); //variable that uses the getSomeString method

}
```

I'll say it here again, I am using JNI. I have gotten errors saying the lib.so file I create has undefined variables, I don't know if this is helpful information.
Any help would be appreciated. Sorry about the long post, I am quite lost.

Comment: What happens to the malloced memory after you assign path to convertedVar

Comment: @NeilKirk I do not do anything in particular to it. I used malloc to make sure I had enough room to append a '\0' to the end so it would be recognized as a cstring.

Comment: I'm not really familiar with JNI, but what makes you think `passedPath` is NUL-terminated? Java doesn't usually work this way. A cursory search suggests you may instead be expected to call `env->GetArrayLength(passedPath)` to discover the array size.

Comment: Also: `convertedVar[length1] = '\0'; convertedVar = (char*)path;`. This makes no sense. You painstakingly allocate memory, copy data over to it - then promptly overwrite the pointer to said memory with the pointer to data that's about to go away as soon as the function returns.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Where do you see a pointer to data? And yes, I agree with you're point on `(char*)path`, my intention there was to be able to use `printf("%s",path)` since %s prints until a '\0'. This was redundant to do, but the original problem still persists.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Your code boils down to `char* p = malloc(...); p = somethingElse;`. This allocates some memory, then promptly loses the means to access that memory, so that it cannot ever be used. On the other part: if you are aware `path` is not NUL-terminated, what exactly do you expect `strlen(path)` to return?

Comment: Ah, I see you point now. This indeed does not make sense. So if I got rid of everything from `int length1` ... all the way to `convertedVar[length1]...`, but kept the convertedVar = (char*)path, would that make more sense?

Comment: I believe you should go the other way round: get rid of `convertedVar = (char*)path;`, keep the lines that precede it. Only instead of strlen, calculate the array size via `env->GetArrayLength`

Comment: Thank you, everything works now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> char* convertedVar = (char*)malloc(length1+1);
> memcpy(convertedVar,path,length1);
> convertedVar[length1] = '\0';
> convertedVar = (char*)path;
> ```

I'm pretty sure this last line shouldn't be there. You are going through this `malloc`/`memcpy` dance, then promptly drop this allocated-and-initialized block of memory on the floor, and make `convertedVar` point to something else instead.

Further, I'm pretty sure `path` pointer will become invalid as soon as the function returns.

Comment: You mention the function returning and invalidating a pointer, why would this invalidate the `path` pointer?

Comment: I'm not really familiar with JNI. My educated guess is, the memory block represented by `passedPath` is pinned for the duration of this JNI call. Once the function returns, the block will be unpinned and subject to the whims of the garbage collector, which may then move it around or deallocate it at any time.

Answer (score 0):

> extern const char* globalVariable;

This declares the variable, but doesn't define it. You also need to provide a definition, in exactly one source file (not in a header file):

```
const char* globalVariable;
```

Curiously, you know enough to do just that with `someNum` and `someLength`, but not for `globalVariable`.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo, it was originally there. Editted, thanks for the catch, but the problem still persists.

Comment: What exactly is the nature of the problem that still persists? You mentioned error messages: what is the exact text of those messages?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: .../libfoo.so: .../libfoo.so: undefined symbol: globalVariable
 at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary1(ClassLoader.java:1935)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1860)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1850)
 at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:845)
 at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1084)
 at tcr.<clinit>(foo.java:9)